# Windows 7 Backup to new HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup

I have a PC with a pretty old HDD in it, and I want to avoid to lose my datas if it suddenly stops working. There's Windows 7 on the PC, and I already put the System Recovery Tool onto a pendrive. My question is, if I buy a secondary HDD, and I save the backup to that (with System image) , than my old HDD stops working (can't boot from it, etc.), all I have to do is to browse the backup system image in the System Recovery Tool , and it will restore all of my programs and datas, and my PC will work like nothing happened?

Comment: System images made with Windows 7 image tool can only be applied to the hard drive it was made from, you would need to use a 3rd party hard drive imaging tool like Macrium Reflect.

Comment: Oh ok so if I use a 3rd party imagin tool everything should work like I wrote? So I will be able to restore the backup to the new HDD where the backup image is ?

Comment: No you cannot store the image on the drive you wish to apply it to.

Comment: Oh yeah I think i get it. If i want to do backup, i need to buy HDD2 and HDD3, and replace HDD1(which fails) with HDD3 and restore the backup to HDD3 from HDD2. And if I want to clone HDD1, its enough to buy only HDD2.